# How to send requests to different processes using MPI_Irecv

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I want to send request to some processes see if any of them returns anything. if none of them returned anything then the process should return -1. I thought I can do this using [MPI_Irecv](http://www.open-mpi.org/~jsquyres/www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.3/man3/MPI_Irecv.3.php). The problem is that any solution requires that I (have to?) wait and check if any of them of the requests did return. But that's not what I want. I want to send a number of requests and then wait (at most 1 second), if anything was returned fine, if not then the process should return -1. I have written half the method, it would be great if somebody could help with how to complete it.

```
    int findJob(MPI_Comm world, int size, int rank, int target, MPI_Status *status){

    int counter = 0;    
    int req = -1;
    MPI_Status status;

    while(counter < size){

        if(target == rank)
            continue;

        printf("Process %d sending job request to process %d\n",rank,target);
        MPI_Send(&rq, 1, MPI_INT, target,0,world);

        printf("Process %d listening for response from %d\n",rank,target);
        MPI_Irecv(&req, 1, MPI_INT,target,MPI_ANY_TAG,world,&status)

    }

    return req;
}
```

Comment: You cannot send MPI request objects. They only have meaning in the address space where they were created.

Comment: @Jeff i am not returning mpi request object, req is a simple integer.

Comment: Then it would improve your question to use a different term.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for MPI_Probe?